# Problems viewing and displaying SetTempVar results

Tags: ms-access

I want to make a simple timer for processes that I run with a Macro.  I'm using SetTempVar to record the start and end times, and a simple query to calculate the elapsed time.

The macro is:

[image]

Then the query is simply:

```
SELECT [tempvars]![ProcessStart] AS Start, [TempVars]![ProcessEnd] AS [End], DateDiff("s",[start],[end]) AS Seconds;
```

But the output is strange:

[image]

The 2 fields from SetTempVar display in some strange font.  However, the elapsed time of 84 seconds is correct.

How can I display the start and end times correctly?

Comment: How are you viewing the two fields?  Yes I see the image, but is this the query's default datasheet view, or is it on a form?  Either way, you should be able to go to design view, go to the field properties and specify a format, perhaps "Short Time" or something similar.  Not sure why it's showing like you demonstrate to begin with, but apparently Access cannot determine the TempVar types automatically, so it must default to interpreting it as unicode text or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this. It's an odd issue.

The TempVar gets interpreted as a string, though it contains a date. The binary date data gets interpreted as UTF-16 characters, displaying random characters (often Chinese since there are many Chinese characters in UTF-16).

I'd consider this a bug in Access. Queries should correctly determine variable type, and that's apparently somehow going wrong.

To display the date value, use either `Format` or `CDate`.

If you're interested in a time difference, I recommend formatting it as *Long Time*:

```
SELECT Format([tempvars]![ProcessStart], "Long Time") AS Start, Format([TempVars]![ProcessEnd], "Long Time") AS [End], DateDiff("s",[start],[end]) AS Seconds;
```

Comment: I also had to change the [start] and [end] references in the DateDiff call - but the formatting fixed the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: This is not the only scenario in which Access does not properly determine data types for formatting.  An immediate example is when using nz() in SQL. One might think Access should inspect the datatype of a variant value passed into and/or out of nz() for determining type, but it does not do so in choosing what format to show in the results.  Sorry that I don't have other concrete examples, but there are other such cases, but generally this type of inconsistency happens when there is a data exchange between the SQL engine, VBA, macros, etc.  It could be called a "bug", but it is not unique.